# Set file date modification via touch function

Tags: php, date, time

I have read http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php on how to set a file modification date, but my date format is:

```
$date = "5/11/2017 08:32 PM EST";
```

How can I touch the file with that date?

```
$filename = "text.txt";

if (!touch($filename, $date)) {
    echo 'Whoops, something went wrong...';
} else {
    echo 'Touched file with success';
}
```

Comment: `strtotime` can convert a date string to Unix timestamp

Comment: touch() needs the second parameter to be a UNIX timestamp. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php this is a way of doing it but I suggest you use the DateTime methods to ensure the best result

Comment: Btw; you have other questions with  what look to be solutions; best to mark them as solved. They're considered as still be unsolved/open.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`strtotime()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert it into the correct format:

```
$filename = "text.txt";

if (!touch($filename, strtotime($date))) {
echo 'Whoops, something went wrong...';
} else {
echo 'Touched file with success';
}
```

If you are 100% sure of the format, use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to ensure 100% accuracy (regardless of locale or region):

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("n/d/Y h:i A T", $date);

if (!touch($filename, $datetime->getTimestamp())) {
echo 'Whoops, something went wrong...';
} else {
echo 'Touched file with success';
}
```

You can see [here](https://3v4l.org/mYlVB) the result is the same using `strtotime()` or `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

Comment: Best to check OP's previous questions ;-) I gave them a [slight friendly nudge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814911/set-file-date-modification-via-touch-function#comment76610488_44814911)

Comment: @Fred-ii- What do I get from checking OP's previous questions? Should I have done something different?

Comment: Well, many a time, people post many questions and get many solutions but don't mark them off as solved. They post, they get their solutions and run off. Not sure if you'll see a green tick here though, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Fred, True story :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- So you're saying I should avoid answering questions from posters who don't accept answers?

Comment: No, not at all, That is entirely your choice :-)

Comment: the date format is 150131 (jan 31 2015) strtotime is not working

Comment: hi , still earning this site sorry for delay  = it say ssuccess but file date has not changed

Comment: @youtube-dlfan Are you sure the format is correct? Ensure you're passing the correct arguments to `DateTime::createFromFormat()` and getting the correct date back.